# yahoo finance YQL issue - connection error. link also does not work

Tags: yahoo, yql, yahoo-finance

Does anyone else experience problems when connecting to a Yahoo Finance community table?

The YQL console gives me a connection error message. Do others have the same issue

YQL query:

```
select * from yahoo.finance.historicaldata where symbol = "YHOO" and startDate = "2009-09-11" and endDate = "2010-03-10"
```

The ichart link shows a Yahoo warning that has been on there for a long time now.

The ichart link warning:

```
Yahoo Will be right back...    
Thank you for your patience.
Our engineers are working quickly to resolve the issue.
```

The YQL console output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<query xmlns:yahoo="http://www.yahooapis.com/v1/base.rng"
    yahoo:count="0" yahoo:created="2017-05-18T01:14:26Z" yahoo:lang="en-US">
    <diagnostics>
        <url execution-start-time="0" execution-stop-time="1" execution-time="1"><![CDATA[http://www.datatables.org/yahoo/finance/yahoo.finance.historicaldata.xml]]></url>
        <publiclyCallable>true</publiclyCallable>
        <cache execution-start-time="3" execution-stop-time="3"
            execution-time="0" method="GET" type="MEMCACHED"><![CDATA[ada24345cde45cf8aefbdeee1216fea1]]></cache>
        <url execution-start-time="4" execution-stop-time="14"
            execution-time="10" http-status-code="502" http-status-message="Connection refused"><![CDATA[http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?a=8&b=11&e=10&g=d&c=2009&d=2&f=2010&s=YHOO]]></url>
        <query execution-start-time="3" execution-stop-time="15"
            execution-time="12" params="{url=[http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?a=8&amp;b=11&amp;e=10&amp;g=d&amp;c=2009&amp;d=2&amp;f=2010&amp;s=YHOO]}"><![CDATA[select * from csv(0,1) where url=@url]]></query>
        <cache execution-start-time="15" execution-stop-time="16"
            execution-time="1" method="GET" type="MEMCACHED"><![CDATA[50ca55b0c486cc3071c5561ad3a43711]]></cache>
        <url execution-start-time="16" execution-stop-time="57"
            execution-time="41" http-status-code="502" http-status-message="Connection refused"><![CDATA[http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?a=8&b=11&e=10&g=d&c=2009&d=2&f=2010&s=YHOO]]></url>
        <csv>Column mismatch: [&lt;!DOCTYPE_html&gt;] vs     font: 300 18px "helvetica neue, helvetica, verdana, tahoma, arial, sans-serif;</csv>
        <query execution-start-time="16" execution-stop-time="57"
            execution-time="41" params="{columnsNames=[&lt;!DOCTYPE_html>], url=[http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?a=8&amp;b=11&amp;e=10&amp;g=d&amp;c=2009&amp;d=2&amp;f=2010&amp;s=YHOO]}"><![CDATA[select * from csv(2,0) where url=@url and columns=@columnsNames]]></query>
        <javascript execution-start-time="2" execution-stop-time="57"
            execution-time="55" instructions-used="27497" table-name="yahoo.finance.historicaldata"/>
        <user-time>58</user-time>
        <service-time>53</service-time>
        <build-version>2.0.118</build-version>
    </diagnostics> 
    <results/>
</query>
```

Comment: face the same problem. Seems like the links is dead as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yahoo has officially confirmed that the Yahoo Finance API has been discontinued in the following thread in the Yahoo Help Community (see posts by username Nixon):

https://forums.yahoo.net/t5/Yahoo-Finance-help/Is-Yahoo-Finance-API-broken/m-p/250503#U250503